# Can you buy 4 houses and a hotel in the same turn in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly

Can you buy 4 houses for each of your properties and then right after turn them in and instead buy hotels for each property **in the same turn**?

I was taught you had to wait until your next turn to buy hotels.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The other question asks about multiple houses only - no mention of house and hotel together.

Comment: The other question does in fact ask about hotels. Only the title left out reference to hotels, which I've corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You can purchase 4 houses on each property and upgrade to hotels right away as no where in the rules mentions limits on how quickly you can upgrade housing. Any rule that says you have to wait would be a house rule and nothing official. Monopoly is one of games where the rules are misunderstood and house rules are often considered official rules.

[Rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/monopoly/game-rules.php)

> When a player owns all the properties in a color-group, he or she may
> buy houses from the Bank.
>
> You may buy as many houses as your judgment and financial standing
> will allow, but you cannot erect more than one house on any one
> property of any color-group until you have built one house on every
> property of that group.
>
> The price you must pay the Bank for each house is shown on your Title
> Deed card for the property on which you erect the house.
>
> The owner still collects double rent from an opponent who lands on the
> unimproved properties of his/her complete color-group.
>
> When a player has four houses on each property of a complete
> color-group, they may buy a hotel from the Bank and erect it on any
> property of the color-group. Only one hotel may be erected on any one
> property.
>
> As you build evenly, you must also break down evenly if you sell
> houses back to the Bank.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you can't go straight from empty properties to hotels if there are not enough houses in the bank.

Comment: @MatthewJensen I did mention buying all 4 houses and then upgrading them to hotels which I think covers that. And the rules I quoted state you have to have 4 houses on each property group to buy hotels.

Comment: That's fair. It's probably not all that relevant to the question either. It's mostly about timing restrictions.